# Application of Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

Define a category k such that obj(k)=N and in which also the product of family
 Ai € k is the greatest common divisor of A1,A2…….An and the co product of them is the least common multiple of them.

Answer (score 2):

Every partial order $\mathsf{P} = (X, R)$ gives rise to a category $C_{\mathsf{P}}$ whose objects are the elements $x \in X$, and such that for any $x,y \in X$, if $xRy$ then there's one and only one arrow $x\to y$, and if not $xRy$ then there are no arrows $x\to y$.

In this induced category $C_{\mathsf{P}}$, products correspond to $\inf$s (greatest lower bounds) in $\mathsf{P}$, and coproducts correspond to $\sup$s (least upper bounds) in $\mathsf{P}$. (*If you have already proved this, great; if not, prove it.*)

The "divides" relation, $a\mid b$, on $\mathbb{N}$ is a partial order, in which "greatest common divisor" and "least common multiple" are $\inf$ and $\sup$ respectively. (*If you have already proved this, great; if not, prove it.*)

Those are the pieces you need to complete and/or assemble.